No Sound on AnduinOS with Intel HDA
i got a Tesla-Monoblock (from a other country) with Windows 10 preinstalled. Because i use and want to use since also many years before Linux as OS i installed AndiunOS (which was a Ubuntu derivat). The problem i have was that i dont get any sound output there. Within the preinstalled Windows 10 the sound was there but i dont want to use Windows. Maybe someone can help me to bring back the sound output. For this many thanks in advance!
Here are some outputs ...
$ cat /proc/asound/cards

0 [PCH]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
         HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf220000 irq 134

$ head -n 1 /proc/asound/card*/codec#*

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Realtek ALC662 rev3

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#2 <==
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI

$ inxi -A

  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio
  driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.8.0-49-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes

$ uname -a

Linux ubuntu-pc 6.8.0-49-generic #49~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov  6 17:42:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a

  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description: AnduinOS 1.0.3
  Release: 1.0.3
  Codename: jammy

$ lspci

  00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 610 (rev 04)
  00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
  00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
  00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
  00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H110 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
  00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
  00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
  00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
  01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
  02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)

$ /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf  (at the end of file)

  options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode1
  options snd-hda-intel model=basic
  options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1

What i did ...

In alsamixer i turned off all muted channels and turn up the volume in all colums.
Like this Post i add the option-lines (see before) in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf reload the alsamixer with sudo alsa force-reload and make a restart
Check and probe all from this Post and this Post

But i still got no sound output :(
Maybe someone can help me to bring the sound back. Thanks in advance!
Let me know if there will be a need of more outputs.
Regards,
Andreas

What about pactl list short sinks and aplay -l?

$ pactl list short sinks 0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz RUNNING
and
$ aplay -l Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]   Sub-Geräte: 1/1   Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0 Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]   Sub-Geräte: 0/1   Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
